# I want to get data from the user without them using a form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm currently working on a website which posts a web novel. I need a system to make user send the chapter id and get the chapter which uses that id maybe like:

```
<a href="chapters/1">Chapter1</a>
<a href="chapters/2">Chapter2</a>
<a href="chapters/3">Chapter3</a>
```

I don't want to create a specific html page for every novel chapter that we posts and use a system to maybe get the links "/chapter/**id**" part or send the id when clicked to an element and pull data from the database using the id given. I searched up in the net and couldn't find anything useful.

**Note:** The database is like this;

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    chapter_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    chapter_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    chapter_text = RichTextField(default=None)
    chapter_footnotes = RichTextField(default=None, blank=True)
```

Comment: you want to render the chapter's information thats all ?

Comment: yes I'll just render chapter title, chapter text and the footnotes @Yasser_1D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) like you mentioned in your description

```
// urls.py 

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path("chapter/<int:chapter_id>", views.chapter, name="chapter"),
]
```

The ID entered there can essentially be used to get the associated chapter in views.py

```
// views.py

def chapter(request, chapter_id):

    chapter = Chapter.models.get(id=chapter_id)

    return render(request, "yourtemplate.html", {"chapter": chapter})
```

Then you can render them in your HTML template

```
// yourtemplate.html

{{ chapter.chapter_title }}

{{ chapter.chapter_text }}

{{ chapter.chapter_footnotes }}
```